# issue in getting record which has apostrophy value in column

Tags: mysql

In my table I have a record such as =>  `Base\'ball`.
When I execute `SELECT` query it fetch that column value as same  =>  `Base\'ball`.
But I want that value to appear as `Baseball`.

So how can I do that in sql query?

Comment: what is your current query?

Comment: "SELECT column from tablename"
and it comes with Base\'ball but I need it to come with Baseball

Comment: If the literal text contains the `\'`, then you will have to add some logic to remove it.

Comment: are there other values like this or just this one

Comment: @Bhavik:  there may be multiple values and that is not possible to run a loop and remove that slash :(

Comment: Have you tried with `TRIM`..

Comment: do you want to remove it or do you want to retrieve it without '

Comment: `replace` will work for you... try it like `replace(field_name, find the string, replace found string with this string)`

Answer (score 0):

try this `Query`:

```
select REPLACE(your_field, 'Base\\\'ball', 'Baseball')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%Base\'ball%'
```

**Update:**

```
select REPLACE(your_field, '\'', '')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%\'%'
```

Comment: this can be one solution but I have just given example as Basa\'ball and there may be multiple values like this and I can not compare those individually that is the main issue

Comment: @AtulAgrawal- Try the **Updated** Query

Comment: Don't you just love it when the OP states a problem then, after he gets the answer, says his problem is different.

Comment: @Marichyasana- Any personal experiences?

Answer (score 0):

try instead of doing that in query.
fetch result and apply mechanism of replace on that.

```
$baseball = "Base\'ball.";
    echo $baseball = str_replace("\'","",$baseball);
```

working perfactly...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `replace`

Replace will work like below,

`select column_name from table_name REPLACE(column_name, '\\\'', '');`

You can use one (or some combination) of MySQL's string functions.

E.g., to get you started...

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('this-is-example-string','example',1);`

Hope it helps.